# what symmetry property is related to $f(x)+f(1/x)=1$?

Tags: functions, symmetry, symmetric-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y6tt.png)we need to figure out the symmetry related to  $$()+(1/x)=1$$ function? What symmetry should $ f(x)+f(1/x)=1$ follow? My teacher gave me this problem and I'm quite not sure how to solve this and looking for help here

This  graph satisfies this very relation. Actually I want to know what symmetry  this graph follows

Comment: If $g(x) = f(x) + f(\frac{1}{x})$, then clearly $g(x) = g(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ I'll take my nobel in the mail, tyvm

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I am not sure, if I understand what you are saying. But the range of $f$ is positive integer given.

Comment: @KNilesh as written the domain and range of the function don't make sense. $\frac{1}{x}$ is never an integer, except when $x=\pm1$. Probably a more sensible one would be $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Comment: Which kind of answer do you expect here? The closest I can imagine to "what symmetry" in the sense of a _named_ kind of symmetry is so say that your condition is equivalent to $x\mapsto f(a^x)-\frac12$ being an **odd** function ...

Answer (score 0):

For the simplicity assume that $f$ is a function form the set of no-zero reals $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ to $\Bbb R$. Put $\Bbb R_1=\{x\in\Bbb R: |x|>1\}$. Then a family  of all functions $f$ satisfying the given condition can be described as a family of all functions $f: \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ for which there exist a function $g:\Bbb R_1\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in\Bbb R_1$, $f(1)=f(-1)=1/2$, and  $f(x)=1-g(1/x)$ for each $x\in (-1,0)\cup (0,1)$.

This property of a function $f$ can be understood as a symmetry, but I think this is loose and does not correspond to the usual symmetries of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. For instance, there not necessary exists a non-identity motion of the real plane, which transforms the graph of the function $f$ to itself, as holds, for instance, for such symmetric functions as odd, even or periodic.